# Hudson will not start on Windows 7? JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 

Tags: ant, hudson

I'd like to setup Hudson to work with Ant. I am using it for the first time, and when I try:
`java -jar hudson.war` it starts doing something, but stops on the line:

```
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 59204
```

I am running Windows 7, also the Java Web Start for hudson does not start.

Comment: what does this have to do with Android? please remove this tag

Comment: done, sorry, I need to setup a CI for an android project, but it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the log line you posted. I assume you started a browser with http://localhost:8080. In that case post the whole printout from your Hudson start.

Comment: Have you tried deploying Hudson on a Servlet container such as Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Check if that port is actually reachable from the node.  At the node you can try to `telnet MASTER_IP 59204`.  The Hudson master machine may have a firewall that's currently blocking such access.

Hudson by default uses a random port number for each node to connect via JNLP.  You can configure it to use a fixed port number.  This works well if you have a firewall and only want to expose a limited number of ports for connection from the outside.  Go to **Manage Hudson** and change *TCP port for JNLP slave agents* to a fixed port number.